# pyDrive is giving FileNotDownloadableError error

Tags: python, pydrive

I am trying to download a file with PyDrive from google drive. 
I followed instruction http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#download-file-content.  And it is working properly from my own domain.

Log is as below.

```
$ python driveDownload.py

Your browser has been opened to visit:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=837780293427-8m0mkibmrn8gg44i77pjg54ga70kpgae.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline 

Authentication successful.
title: a.xlsx, id: 0BzV-wECmF8MQTkdyQ0FHaVdwYlU
file Title identiefied :a.xlsx
aFromDrive.xlsx downloaded
```

I am trying the same thing from my client's domain and it is giving following error

```
$ python driveDownload.py

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=971731530622-7tdt9qhakv6q7i4edpfnqb5h7826eslv.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline                                                                                                                              

Authentication successful.
title: a.xlsx, id: 1l073W5s4dE0-dhFUXAMB-XROvOUC2z51NbfY69-bvIo
 file Title identiefied :a.xlsx                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                             
  File "driveDownload.py", line 29, in <module>                
    myFile.GetContentFile(myLocalPath)                         
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pydrive/files.py", line 167, in GetContentFile
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pydrive/files.py", line 36, in _decorated     
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pydrive/files.py", line 210, in FetchContent  
pydrive.files.FileNotDownloadableError: No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata
```

My code driveDownload.py is below

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
import os
#authentication via the browser
#note... client_secrets.json is required for this that leads
#to the user authentication
gauth = GoogleAuth()
# gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

#accessing the drive
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


# Auto-iterate through all files that matches this query
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
fileName2Download= 'a.xlsx'
myLocalPath = 'aFromDrive.xlsx'
for file1 in file_list:
    print 'title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id'])
    if file1['title'] == fileName2Download:
        print ' file Title identiefied :%s'% (file1['title']) 
        myFile = drive.CreateFile({'id': file1['id']})
        if os.path.exists(myLocalPath):
            os.remove(myLocalPath)

        myFile.GetContentFile(myLocalPath)
        print '%s downloaded ' %(myLocalPath)
        break
#         file1.download()
```

Are there some settings that are missing ? I am able to list all the files in my client's google drive. However error appears when I am trying to download the file to my local disk

Comment: I solved the problem.  I had edited file with google sheet on my client domain and its mimeType had changed. Once I gave mimeType  it started working myFile.GetContentFile(myLocalPath,mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because I was trying to download a folder directly. Double check that your mimeType is something which can be downloaded through PyDrive.

Answer (score 0):

in my case id was wrong, I used the id of the folder in which the file was situated, so be sure that the id is of that file only and not of the folder

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a folder, make sure you copy the file ID( right click->get shareable link->copy the last part of the link) not the folder ID.